# How to convert table variables into a different class using curly braces instead of variable names/dot accessor

Tags: matlab

I am trying to follow instructions [here](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/calculations-on-tables.html#zmw57dd0e23038) to use curly braces and indices to convert table variables from `double` to `uint8`. However, it does not seem to be working. For example

```
temp = {1, 2, 3};
tempTable = cell2table(temp, 'VariableNames', {'a' 'b' 'c'});
```

Converting using variable names works fine:

```
tempTable.a = uint8(tempTable{:, 'a'});
```

with `class` applied on the table variables giving:

```
ans = 

    'uint8'    'double'    'double'
```

However, now try using variable name inside curly braces to do the conversion:

```
for varName = tempTable.Properties.VariableNames
    tempTable{:, varName} = uint8(tempTable{:, varName});
end
```

And applying `class`:

```
ans = 

    'uint8'    'double'    'double'
```

that is, the `for` loop actually did not do the conversion.

Using explicit indices also fails:

```
for i = 2:3
    tempTable{:, i} = uint8(tempTable{:, i});
end
```

still gives

```
ans = 

    'uint8'    'double'    'double'
```

How can I convert a whole bunch of variables into `uint8` class without having to explicitly call `tempTable.varName = uint8...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following codes work:

```
for ii = 1 : length(tempTable.Properties.VariableNames)
    tempTable.(tempTable.Properties.VariableNames{ii}) = uint8(tempTable{:, tempTable.Properties.VariableNames{ii}});
end
```

The major difference between my code and yours is how we're performing our assignment. Here's my guess for why my codes work: Table is by itself a class, assignment statement, indexing, operators and functions applied to them might not always behave the same way as you see with other classes like `struct` or `cell`.

Comment: thanks, your method of dynamically generating the variable name for use in the dot accessor works. However, I am not satisfied about your explanation on why my method doesn't work. You should be able to index into the table using a cell array of variable names. Can you also explain why using the indices do not work?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I've also changed the code a little bit, because my first version will actually also change the content not just the class.

Comment: This is very interesting indeed. Thanks. What do you mean by change the content, not just the class? Does it matter?

Comment: Yes. Curiously, It changed the values 1,2,3 to 3,3,3. I think there's something funny about how it can be indexed. This is actually my first time to learn about this class. It seems quite peculiar to me.